# I am trying to program a MLX90288 Hall effect sensor and write parameters into its EEPROM

Tags: arduino, byte, bit, sensors, eeprom

The datasheet provided shows parameters that have addresses and bit size. I want to understand how I can use these with my arduino to program this sensor. Specifically what does the notation "[4:0]" mean next to a parameter.
All calibration parameters on the MLX90288 are stored in a 32 x 16bit non-volatile EEPROM.

"The EEPROM parameters from the first 29 addresses are stored with triple redundancy, to correct if any EEPROM bit would loose its content, by using majority voting. Consequently, an EEPROM word in this part of EEPROM only holds the information of 5 calibration bits + 1 locking bit at index 15. The EEPROM word stored at address 0 thus looks like this:
{LOCK0,PARAM[4:0],PARAM[4:0],PARAM[4:0]}"

So here it says that the clamp voltages are programmable but i don't have knowledge of what the bits mean in the brackets and how I can convert them to hexadecimal:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g. CLPHigh[9:0] means 10 bits (from 0 to 9).

With 10 bits the maximum value = dec 1023 (bin 11 1111 1111).

Vdd = 5 Volts, the range is from 0% to 100% (0V to 5V).
The resolution is 0.098% (100 / 1023 = approx. 0.098)

Say you want to set CLPHigh at 25% : 25/0.098 = 255 (= 0xFF)

The Output DAC Resolution = 0.0244, so 1/4 of outDac = 0.098